# How access a website page with Google credentials using python?

Tags: python, google-api

I have tried access a Google ecosystem page after get credentials. My app will manage Calendar events, using python and Google api. I've got credentials, list events, read summaries, etc. But If I try to access a web page as (with AuthorizedSession class):

https://calendar.google.com

I notice that this page asks for login/password from Google.
Maybe this task is out of the specified scope. Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

**Code:**

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession
import pickle
import os.path
import requests
from pathlib import Path


SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']

CREDENTIALS_FILE = 'client_secret_123456ABCDEFG.apps.googleusercontent.com.json'

def get_credentials():
   creds = None
   # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
   # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
   # time.
   if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
       with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
           creds = pickle.load(token)
   # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
   if not creds or not creds.valid:
       if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
           creds.refresh(Request())
       else:
           flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
               CREDENTIALS_FILE, SCOPES)
           creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

       # Save the credentials for the next run
       with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
           pickle.dump(creds, token)

   return creds



authed_session = AuthorizedSession(get_credentials())

response = authed_session.request(
    'GET', 'https://calendar.google.com/')
print(response.status_code)
....
```

Answer (score 0):

The url calendar.google.com is not in the same scope than the API.

Here's a part of the API doc :

> Here's the OAuth 2.0 scope information for the Google Calendar API:
> Scope     Meaning https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar    read/write
> access to Calendars https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly
> read-only access to Calendars
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events   read/write access to
> Events https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events.readonly
> read-only access to Events
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.settings.readonly    read-only
> access to Settings
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.addons.execute   run as a
> Calendar add-on

Edit: All actions for the Google calendar API are available in the endpoints described in the doc